# (Spring boot + Java) Download API for files larger than 1 GB

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am creating rest API for downloading files in spring boot and java.
I used this https://o7planning.org/en/11765/spring-boot-file-download-example for example.

here it is given three examples, I tried for the first two, my file size is larger than 1 GB:

1) ByteArrayResource:
This produces an out of memory in my server

2) InputStreamResource: This produces java.io.EOFException

In both cases, whenever my file increases after 300 to 400 MB, the download stops and the server failed.

Please suggest how to make a better download API, which does not fail for larger size files.

Edit: I tried all the suggestions given in comments, But in all ways i get this only, adding logs also.

```
ERROR o.s.c.s.i.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter - Uncaught exception thrown
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$3.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:264)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

Comment: try to wrap it with BufferedReader

Comment: Google for spring rest template download large file.

Comment: please check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-download-large-file

Comment: You can try using Java NIO

Comment: Write to the outputstream directly and don't use the other 2 options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 @GetMapping(
        value = "/download",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> download() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("/my/file/path");
    org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource resource = new org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource(file.toURI());
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .contentLength(resource.contentLength())
            .header(
                    HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                    String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", resource.getFilename()))
            .body(resource);

}
```